# How to debug VSCODE python using local packages

Tags: python, azure, function, package

import logging
import sys
import os
from LoggingHelper.main import LoggingHelper <-- Import "LoggingHelper.main" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
from LoggingHelper.models import logDataclass as ldc <-- Import "LoggingHelper.main" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
from .configs.project_configs import *
kafka_config = {}
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request <-- Import "LoggingHelper.main" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse <-- Import "LoggingHelper.main" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
import fastapi <-- Import "LoggingHelper.main" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
import azure.functions as func <-- Import "LoggingHelper.main" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
import nest_asyncio
from starlette.middleware import Middleware <-- Import "LoggingHelper.main" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware <-- Import "LoggingHelper.main" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
nest_asyncio.apply()
from TSAuthHelper import FastAPIAuthHelper <-- Import "LoggingHelper.main" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
import json
import os
import time
import traceback
import pickle

I have a local library/package in ".python_packages\lib\site-packages" called "LoggingHelper", "fastapi", "starlette/middleware", etc. But I can't compile those in VSCODE.
They work just fine if I publish them all to Azure Functions, but not locally. I need to debug them locally on my VSCODE.

I have been trying to read everything I can, change the interpreter, etc. But I'm not a developer and need some guidance.

from .python_packages/fastapi import FastAPI

from fullpath/.python_packages/fastapi import FastAPI

nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

When running locally you may need to specify the major version of Python you intend to use. Normally on Linux the first line of a Python3 program would be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 

import os
...
```

Then before importing modules that are in an unusual location you might need to add a line:

```
sys.path.append("/fullpath/to/custom/modules/dir")
```

then you should be able to import modules that are in that directory.